Incorrect Display of Special Characters in Sender Name Using Microsoft Graph
When sending an email via Microsoft Graph, the sender's display name (myself) appears as "B?undchen" instead of "Bündchen." This name is not passed to Graph in any way.
Analyzing the message, I found the following:
From: Max B?ndchen <(ommited)@hotmail.com>

Interestingly, if I add an accented character to the body of the email, the display name appears correctly. In this case, the correct encoding is included in the message:
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Max_Bündchen?= <(ommited)@hotmail.com>

I've already tried sending the POST as UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, but the result is the same. I even tried changing my name in the account profile, but that didn't work either.
